# How to create own custom domain name for local-netwrok

Tags: apache, dns

I wanted to host one website in local Network.(it is not accessed by out side the network)
  i install apache server.
  how can i create own domain name for that(i don't want buy any domain name).
  it is my virtual host file

```
    ServerName testing.com
    ServerAlias www.testing.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testing.com/public_html
```

It works only when i put **localhost** as serverName

Comment: You can use whatever host name you want in your http servers virtual host configuration. You only need to take care that this name gets resolved in your local network. Either enter it into the "hosts" file on all systems, or, for a larger network, you need to create a DNS a record in your local DNS resolution solution.

Comment: I try this, but it was not working, it is my virtual host file **ServerName** testing.com
        **ServerAlias** www.testing.com
        **DocumentRoot** /var/www/testing.com/public_html   \n It works only when i put localhost as server name

Comment: Please put additional information into the question itself, there is an `edit` button below it. _Use it._ The definition looks fine, question is how you resolve the name, I'd say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

locahost file

127.0.0.1 somedomain.com